# How do I create a click event to open a specific Bootstrap tab on a different HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two pages. My main page contains links in different places within this page to perform actions such as Edit profile, Change my Password, Upload a profile picture etc.

Main page '**index.html**'

```
<a href="accounts.html">EDIT PROFILE</a>
<a href="accounts.html">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
<a href="accounts.html">UPLOAD PHOTO</a>
```

My second page '**accounts.html**' uses Bootstrap Nav Tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#editProfile" data-toggle="tab"> Edit my profile</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#changePassword" data-toggle="tab">Change my Password</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#uploadPhoto" data-toggle="tab">Upload Photo</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane" id="editProfile">
  BARK BARK
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="changePassword">
  WOFF WOFF
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="uploadPhoto">
  MEOW MEOW
</div>
```

How do I click the link on the main page and open the correct corresponding Bootstrap Tab on the second page?

```
<!-- CLICK ON LINK WITHIN MAIN PAGE -->
$('#editProfile').on('click', function() {
    $('body').load( "accounts.html" ).find('active').removeClass('active');
    $('li.active').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use localStorage for this solution. The first, save id of the selected tab that you click on index.html into localStorage. And then, on the account.html you get value selected tab from localStorage. Here is the sample, hope to help, my friend!

--In the index.html

```
<a href="#" id="editProfile">EDIT PROFILE</a>
<a href="#" id="changePass">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
<a href="#" id="uploadPhoto">UPLOAD PHOTO</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('id'));
        window.location.replace("accounts.html"); 
    });
});
```

--In the account.html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active" id="lieditProfile">
        <a href="#editProfile" data-toggle="tab"> Edit my profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="lichangePass">
        <a href="#changePass" data-toggle="tab">Change my Password</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="liuploadPhoto">
    <a href="#uploadPhoto" data-toggle="tab">Upload Photo</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="editProfile" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Edit the profile.</h3>      
    </div>
    <div id="changePass" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Change Password</h3>      
    </div>
    <div id="uploadPhoto" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Upload Photo</h3>      
    </div>    
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        $('li').removeClass();
        $('#li'+ activeTab).addClass('active');
        $('.tab-pane').removeClass('in active');
        $('#' + activeTab).addClass('in active show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: document fragment identifiers are a better choice as they can be added directly to the `href`.

Comment: @Tomato32 The code above seems close. However, I need to add the class of active to the nav tabs li, and the associated tab-pane on accounts.html, to make it highlight what tab you are on an display the right content in the tab pane.

Comment: @Al-76:  It's Ok. I will edit my solution. Sorry for response lately.

Comment: @Tomato .. Thank you very much for looking at this again. Unfortunately, it removes the class of active once the account page has loaded. Plus it won't add 'active' to the li of nav-tabs or open the corresponding tab-pane. I appreciate your code as its better than what I could do :)

Comment: @Al-76: Sorry, my friend. You can clarify about this "it removes the class of active once the account page has loaded". Maybe I can help you better.

Comment: Hello @Tomato32. I must have had a typo as it now works to get the active class on the li. You have been very kind in helping me with a solution. I just need to get the active class on the tab-panel as well now alysebastien.fr/user.html

Comment: @Al-76: Lol, my sample runs Ok :)). But you can add "in" class in your sample. I edited my solution. See the modified in the last two rows.Finally, you can add my skype: manhtran32 to make friend :))